# Workflow Services Persistence not working

Tags: workflow, persistence, service

I have created a state workflow service and set its persistance in app.config.

```
<add type="System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.SqlWorkflowPersistenceService, System.Workflow.Runtime, Version=3.0.00000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
               connectionString="Initial Catalog=WFPersistence;Data Source=LUKA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
               LoadIntervalSeconds="1"
               UnLoadOnIdle="true"/>
```

Everything is OK when UNLoadONIdle is set to false, but when I set it to true, and the client call the method that the workflow service expose... it hangs and after some time it trows the following error:

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9985354. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Comment: Resolved!!!
The problem were the Custom objects references I had in workflow. So I declared them [Serializable] and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!!! The problem were the Custom objects references I had in workflow. So I declared them [Serializable] and now it works.